# Program does not see Overloaded Constructor

Tags: java, constructor

I'm getting an error in my code (it's the last line of my assignment and I can't seem to solve it) which is in the addStudent method. It says my attempt to access an overloaded constructor is actually attempting to access the default constructor, and that there are no variables for me to pass through. So, in a nutshell:

"studentArray[i] = new Student(firstname, lastname, gender, sClass, sID);"

is trying to access:

"public void Student(){}"

but I want it to access:

"public void Student(String firstname, String lastname, String gender, String sClass, String sID)"

Thanks for the help!

-AndresL

```
public void Student() 
{
    setFirstName("Unknown");
    setLastName("Unknown");
    setGender("Unknown");
    setClass("Freshman");
    setID("0000");
}

public void Student(String firstname, String lastname, String gender, String sClass, String sID) 
{
    setFirstName(firstname);
    setLastName(lastname);
    setGender(gender);
    setClass(sClass);
    setID(sID);
}

public static boolean addStudent(String firstname, String lastname, String gender, String sClass, String sID)
{
    for (int i=0; i<studentArray.length; i++) 
    {
        if (studentArray[i] == null)
        {
            studentArray[i] = new Student(firstname, lastname, gender, sClass, sID);
            totStudent++;
        }else {JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Max students reached.");}
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: After 1.5 years, I've realized.... that I'm an idiot. :p

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are declaring your "constructors" with `void`, actually making them `void` methods, not constructors. Therefore, the compiler can only use the default constructor, which is why you receive that error. So: you should remove the `void` keyword anywhere you try to define a constructor.

Comment: When I do so, the methods set_____ have an error saying "overridable method call in constructor" How do I get rid of it?

Comment: @AndresL Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404301/whats-wrong-with-overridable-method-calls-in-constructors) can help you out here.

Comment: Those "errors" are actually warnings, and they come into play when something is extending your `Student` class. If nothing is extending `Student`, then you can either a) ignore them or b) make `Student` final to get rid of them (i.e. `public final class Student { ... }`)

Answer (score 2):

Remove `void` keywords from your constructors:

```
public void Student(String firstname, String lastname, String gender, String sClass, String sID)
```

change to

```
public Student(String firstname, String lastname, String gender, String sClass, String sID)
```

similarly

```
public void Student()
```

change to

```
public Student()
```

Constructors don't have return types.

Comment: When I do so, the methods set_____ have an error saying "overridable method call in constructor" How do I get rid of it?

Answer (score 1):

Constructors don't have a return type because they return a new Object of the same type as the class they are defined in, when you use them with the new keyword.

Object o = new Object(); // you are calling Object constructor.

-- EDIT --
Also I would recommend changing this

```
public Student() 
{
    setFirstName("Unknown");
    setLastName("Unknown");
    setGender("Unknown");
    setClass("Freshman");
    setID("0000");
}
```

to

```
public Student() 
{
    this("Unknown", "Unknown", "Unknown", "Freshman", "0000"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

constructors dont have a return type not even void. you are declaring your constructors with void, which would make them methods rather than constructors

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `void` from constructors and no need of calling `setter` methods. You may directly access the attributes as below:

```
 public void Student() 
 {
    this.firstName = "Unknown";
    this.lastName = "Unknown";
    this.gender = "Unknown";
    this.class = "Freshman";
    this.ID="0000";
 }
```

Similarly

```
 public void Student(String firstname, String lastname, 
                                         String gender, String sClass, String sID) 
 {
    this.firstName = firstname;
    this.lastName = lastname;
    this.gender = gender;
    this.class = sClass;
    this.ID=sID;
 }
```

You should be all set.

Comment: `class` is a reserved wprd, fyi.